# Rails how to mock Http Post Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, mocking, rspec2, rspec-rails

In my controller I have made this post request with parameters and it worked perfectly

```ruby
parameters = {'email' => "email", 'password' => "password"}      
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://example.com/unsubscriptions'), {'q'=>parameters})
      if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
        @msg = "You have successfully unsubscribed."
      else
        @msg = "Resource not found."
      end
```

In specs controller this is the code

```ruby
   it "should return success message on a successfull Post request to api" do
              parameters = { "email" => 'email', "password" => "password" }
              Net::HTTP.should_receive(:post_form).with(
                  URI.parse("http://example.com/unsubscriptions"), "q" => parameters
              ).and_return(Net::HTTPSuccess)
              post :unsub_uk, parameters
              #assigns(:msg).should eq("You have successfully unsubscribed.")
              response.should be_success
    end
```

I am not being able mock this `Net::HTTP.post_form` request. Any idea or any other way to do this task?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use gem [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock).

Believed solves the problem, because the return should be Net::HTTPSuccess.